# don't want to login google cloud with service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am new at google cloud and this is my first experience with this platform. ( Before I was using Azure )

So I am working on a c# project and the project has a requirement to save images online and for that, I created cloud storage.

not for using the services, I find our that I have to download a service account credential file and set the path of that file in the environment variable.
Which is good and working file

```
RxStorageClient = StorageClient.Create();
```

But the problem is that. my whole project is a collection of 27 different projects and that all are in the same solution and there are multi-cloud storage account involved also I want to use them with docker.

So I was wondering. is there any alternative to this service account system? like API key or connection string like Azure provides?
Because I saw this initialization function have some other options to authenticate. but didn't saw any example

> `RxStorageClient = StorageClient.Create();`

[image]

Can anyone please provide a proper example to connect with cloud storage services without this service account file system

Comment: Doug's answer is correct. If you are planning to use Google Cloud, then you must understand OAuth. GCP authorizes using either OAuth Access Tokens or Identity Tokens. Service Accounts are used to create a Signed JWT which is exchanged for an Access Token. There are no/few shortcuts to authorization and security. The days of API Keys are passing and being phased out in the cloud due to the lack of authorization control and identity management. With the notable exception of AWS, the rest of the industry is moving to OAuth/OIDC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this instead of relying on the environment variable by downloading credential files for each project you need to access.

So for example, if you have three projects that you want to access storage on, then you'd need code paths that initialize the `StorageClient` with the appropriate service account key from each of those projects.

`StorageClient.Create()` can take an optional `GoogleCredential()` object to authorize it (if you don't specify, it grabs the default application credentials, which, one way to set is that GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var).

So on `GoogleCredential`, check out the `FromFile(String)` static call, where the String is the path to the service account JSON file.

Answer (score 2):

There are no examples.  Service accounts are absolutely required, even if hidden from view, to deal with Google Cloud products.  They're part of the [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam) system for authenticating and authorizing various pieces of software for use with various products.  I strongly suggest that you become familiar with the mechanisms of providing a service account to a given program.  For code running outside of Google Cloud compute and serverless products, the current preferred solution involves using environment variables to point to files that contain credentials.  For code running Google (like Cloud Run, Compute Engine, Cloud Functions), it's possible to provide service accounts by configuration so that the code doesn't need to do anything special.